# NoMethodError when calling model's included class methods from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have three included methods on one of my Model's

```
#app/models/foobar.rb
class Foobar
  include Paginate
  include Sort
  include Query
end
```

and in my controller I call one of them:

```
#app/controllers/foobar_controller.rb
Foobar.query(params[:q])
```

But get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `query' for #<Class:0x00000101469400>):
```

I made sure to include them in my application.rb with:

```
#config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Here is query.rb:

```
#lib/query.rb
module Query
  module ClassMethods
    def query params
      (...)
    end
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

Why can't the Controller see that Foobar has these class methods? Does it not have these class methods? Am I missing something when I include the class methods?

Comment: Your example works as expected on my computer. Try reducing the problem further until you have a super simple example. Does the same problem occur when calling from a model? Does the same problem occur if you simplify the `::query` method (like `def query; puts "foo"; end`)?

Comment: It does, I'll further simplify. Maybe start by making sure I can call it from my controller. Thanks for checking for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confusing, but I got it to work. So when I changed `lib/query` to `lib/queryable`, as well as `include Queryable` it works perfectly. Pagination and Sorting works as well. I must have used the word Query somewhere else in my code.

Too bad the solution wasn't more interesting and reason more concrete :(

At least I am on my merry way.